# APNS Location change

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, apple-push-notifications

Hello good morning everyone,

I am developing an iphone app which provide push notification services and location aware. For the Push Notifications everything works and i am able to generate push notification from a web server. So my question is : can i get Latitude and Longitude coordinates using this scenario?

So what i am trying to do is to execute my php script every 1 hour and using device tokens, i would try to get the coordinates and then depending the coordinates it will send appropriate messages like "You are X kms from this place".

Thank you very much for the usual cooperation and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your application to volunteer latitude and longitude info (with the user's permission) and send it back to the web server, but it can only do this if the application is active and running.  The application will not process APNS messages while it is in the background. So, I doubt you can get the app functionality that you want.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for answering back :). I will try to sort out how i can get push when the application is in background.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @Veer I need a similar solution were you ever able to find a work around?